# How to drag and drop an image from Explorer as a NEW file in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I had a very old version of Photoshop and always used drag-and-drop to open an image file from Explorer (Win). Now I have bought Photoshop CC and have regretted it already, several times—it's working differently.

The problem now is when I try to drag-and-drop it tries to create a new layer in the existing open document instead of create a new window as the older version does. Please help me to gain this behavior—I only need to open as a new file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I've found (I had the same problem) is to drag-and-drop on the zone I've marked on the picture (I still do it this way).

[image: Drag-and-drop zone for new file]

Comment: You're 100% right. Eventually I figured out what is going on. The problem is when you have opened files as shown on your picture it will not work. You either use your method or, drag all the opened pictures out from tabs (sorry I don't know the terminology) and drag and drop a new file in the open space. Thanks!

Comment: Many apps work like this, for example word.has the same behaviour as does wordpad etc..